# outputs the sum of chats and missed chats per website Id for a given date range

Tags: javascript, arrays, date, object

i have following array :-

```
[{
        "websiteId": "4f8b36d00000000000000001",
        "date": "2019-04-01T00:00:00.000Z",
        "chats": 121,
        "missedChats": 0
    },
    {
        "websiteId": "4f8b36d00000000000000002",
        "date": "2019-04-01T00:00:00.000Z",
        "chats": 13,
        "missedChats": 0
    },
    {
        "websiteId": "4f8b36d00000000000000001",
        "date": "2019-04-02T00:00:00.000Z",
        "chats": 92,
        "missedChats": 1
    }]
```

Response should be:

a) If the date range is not provided, the sum should be calculated for the entire data set.

```
[{
        "websiteId": "4f8b36d00000000000000001",
        "chats": 121+92,
        "missedChats": 0+1
    },
    {
        "websiteId": "4f8b36d00000000000000002",
        "chats": 13,
        "missedChats": 0
    },
    ]
```

b) if Date range newDate(2019,3,1) new Date(2019,2,1)

```
[{
        "websiteId": "4f8b36d00000000000000001",
        "chats": 121+92,
        "missedChats": 0+1
    },
    {
        "websiteId": "4f8b36d00000000000000002",
        "chats": 13,
        "missedChats": 0
    },
    ]
```

Comment: Hi, so at which point are you stuck? Seems to me to first have to collect all relevant entries into bucks and just sum within each bucket.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Use reduce to sum the values, the below code may help you.
```

```js
let data = [
  {
    websiteId: '4f8b36d00000000000000001',
    date: '2019-04-01T00:00:00.000Z',
    chats: 121,
    missedChats: 0,
  },
  {
    websiteId: '4f8b36d00000000000000002',
    date: '2019-04-01T00:00:00.000Z',
    chats: 13,
    missedChats: 0,
  },
  {
    websiteId: '4f8b36d00000000000000001',
    date: '2019-04-02T00:00:00.000Z',
    chats: 92,
    missedChats: 1,
  },
];

let result = data
  .map(item => item.websiteId)
  .filter((item, index, self) => self.indexOf(item) === index)
  .map(websiteId =>
    data
      .filter(_item => _item.websiteId === websiteId)
      .reduce(
        (r, c) => {
          r.chats += c.chats;
          r.missedChats += c.missedChats;
          r.websiteId = c.websiteId;
          return r;
        },
        {chats: 0, missedChats: 0},
      ),
  );

console.log(result);
```

Comment: thank you but ,how can we fetch these records on between two dates ?

Comment: This answer was helpful for me , do not know why, somebody vote it out not useful